# how to make selenium run 'chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='C:\\selenium\\ChromeProfile'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing code to make selenium take over an instance of chrome that has all my bookmarks and stuff. So I created a chrome profile and I have the command

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='C:\\selenium\\ChromeProfile'
```

this works when you run it in the python terminal, but I can't just put it into the code.

I have tried using

```
import os

os.system("chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='C:\\selenium\\ChromeProfile'")
```

but that returns with

> Failed To Create Data Directory: Google Chrome cannot read and write to its data directory: C\selenium\ChromeProfile

Does someone know what I am doing wrong or a command that will run the chrome command to open this specific profile?

My total code so far looks like this

```
import subprocess
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

os.system("chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir='C:\\selenium\\ChromeProfile'")

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")
chrome_driver = "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
#Print website title to make sure its connected properly
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys('test')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind people, I figured it out. I am posting this here for anyone else in the future who may run into the same issue I did where you want python to open the browser in debug mode on the port.

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\selenium\\ChromeProfile')
chrome_driver = "C:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver, chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Print website title to make sure its connected properly
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys('test')
```

I had to add two lines of

```
chrome_options.add_argument()
```

for some reason it didn't like when I put them in the same parenthesis.
I hope I help someone in the future.